# How can I continue correctly my if statements in my code?

Tags: php

my script should do this:

Check if there is a $startprice and $endprice for a product. Those variables are checked against the $price that is the product's price.

The user is able to add both ($startprice and $endprice) or just one of them or nothing of them.

- In the case that he adds only the
  $startprice, the $price must be
  bigger than this.
- In the case that he adds only the
  $endprice, the $price must be smaller
  than this.
- In the case that he adds both, the
  $price must be between of them.
- In the case that he does not add
  anything, the script will show all
  the results.

If the data satisfies the statements, it will show the product's list. In all cases the product's list code is the same.

****What I did until now is this but I can't continue it correctly.***

The product's price is named $price and I can get it correctly for each product.

```
   <?php
    $startprice = $_GET['startprice'];
    $endprice = $_GET['endprice'];

    // this is the between code and it's the only I know how to do...

    if (($startprice <= $price) && ($endprice >= $price)) { ?>
    <h2> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <strong>  <?php the_title(); ?>  </strong></a></h2>
 <? } ?>
```

Comment: What is theproducts ??? Make the question a more clear

Comment: What is your question?  I have re-read all of that twice and don't see what you are trying to get us to help you with.

Comment: you should have mentioned early on that u are using wordpress! and question is related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. But just try this from what I understood..

```
<?php
    $startprice = isset($_GET['startprice']) ? $_GET['startprice'] : 0;
    $endprice = isset($_GET['endprice']) ? $_GET['endprice'] : PHP_INT_MAX;

    // this is the between code and it's the only I know how to do...

    if (($startprice <= $price) && ($endprice >= $price)) { ?>
    <h2> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <strong>  <?php the_title(); ?>  </strong></a></h2>
 <? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, because you haven't shown us much code:

```
if(!isset($startprice)) $startprice = 0;
if(!isset($endprice)) $endprice = PHP_INT_MAX;

foreach($theproducts as $product) {
    if($product['price'] >= $startprice && $product['price'] <= $endprice) {
        echo $product['name'].'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mikey: Dude. We're not here to write code for you, I'm simply giving a suggestion. You have to give it a bit of thought. Why isn't it working? Did you get an error message? What was it? You haven't given us enough details. If this code doesn't even attempt to do what you ask, sure, down-vote, but "not working" is not a good enough reason. From the info you've given me, yes, this should do exactly what you asked. I'm assuming `$theproducts` is an array, given the name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include more context.

For example, its clear there is some number of products, whose prices are checked against the prices specified by the user.  What is the format of these products, are they in a multidimensional array?

For example, would the price be defined like this:

```
$PRODUCTS[$prod_id]['price'] = 9.99
```

Or maybe in a "price" array, indexed by product id?

```
$PRICE[$prod_id] = 9.99
```

Or maybe in an object?

```
$product->price
```

We need **much** more context to help.